# AWS s3 bucket url redirect

Tags: amazon-s3

In our static s3 bucket, I would like to redirect all urls to our index.html home page.
So, typing in **www.our_site.com/other_page** redirects back to **www.our_site.com**.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `/other_page` actually a page, now, or no?

Comment: There are pages that exist. But even nonexistent pages are supposed to redirect back to index.html.